# Automation Testing of Spark pipeline in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, automation, automated-tests, bigdata

I need to check what are the technology options, we use for automation testing (QA) for the data engineering pipeline in Spark.

Problem Statement : To optimise functional testing of BigData spark job effectively through automation. Need to check effective data creation and validation with running the scenarios in parallel

Answer (score -1):

There are no automation testing tool/technology available to test data pipeline.

However,You can create a custom spark framework to perform data validation in different data zones(L0,L1,L2 etc..)

Spark can read different types of data(csv,xml,json,text,parquet,etc..) into dataframe.

And you can derive a logic to compare between two dataframes.